# How to deploy WildFly datasource with Arquillian?

Tags: java, jboss, integration-testing, wildfly-8, jboss-arquillian

I tried to deploy my datasource as follows:

```
@Deployment(name = "test", order=2)
static WebArchive createDeployment() {
    ShrinkWrap.createFromZipFile(WebArchive, new File("target/test.war")).addAsWebInfResource(new File("src/test/resources/test-DS.xml"), "test-DS.xml")
}
```

but it seems that my datasource is ignored, I see no info about deployment in jboss console.

Is there any other possibility to deploy datasource with arquillian?

```
@Deployment(name = "datasource", order=1)
static ? createDSDeployment() {
    ?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use separate standalone*.xml for arquillian testing and specify your datasource there. For instance, in arquillian.xml:

```
   <configuration>
       ...
       <property name="serverConfig">standalone-test.xml</property>
       ...
   </configuration>
```

and datasource can be described in the `<datasources>` section of that standalone

Comment: I tried and I'm getting: WARNING [org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.MapObject] Configuration contain properties not supported by the backing object org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.embedded.EmbeddedContainerConfiguration
Unused property entries: {serverConfig=standalone-test.xml}
Supported property names: [managementAddress, modulePath, password, bundlePath, managementPort, jbossHome, managementProtocol, cleanServerBaseDir, username]

Comment: I had wrong dependency. embedded instead of managed.             <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-managed</artifactId>